# EF Code-First and nested sets

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, nested-sets, nested-set-model

I would like to create a nested set model inside my database. However, I have a problem, 'cause I don't know how to start the implementation using Entity Framework Code-First.

Lets say I have such class:

```cs
public class Category
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }

    // public int left { get; set; }
    // public int right { get; set; }
}
```

In my model I need **SubCategories** collection as it is right now. However I would like to implement automatic **(implicit)** update of **left** and **right** properties when I add/remove subcategories to/from **SubCategories** collection.

Is it possible?

Thank you for any answer in advance!

Best!

Comment: what exactly are `left` and `right`? fk references to child and parent categories?

Comment: left and right are integers which build a nested set (tree) model.

Comment: Here is the explanation of the nested set model build:
http://blog.bexlab.pl/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/tree_03.PNG (for example root=[left=1,right=20])

Answer (score 2):

Nested sets and object graphs are two totally different models. You shouldn't store both of them in one type; that violates SRP.

Instead, put `Left` and `Right` on your code-first POCOs, load the, and then project/copy that onto objects *of a different type* (which are not entities) with a graph schema.